# How do I add attributes to HTML.BeginForm with ASP.MVC 4?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

I am using the following code:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm(null, null, 
    new { ReturnUrl = ViewBag.ReturnUrl }, FormMethod.Post, 
    new { data-href = "/User/Account/Login"}))
```

Can someone tell me what's wrong with it. I get an error message pointing to data-href and saying:

Invalid anonymous type member declarator. Anonymous type members must be declared with a member assignment, simple name or member access

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `-` (dash) is not a valid C# identifier character. Use `_` (underscore) and it will be transformed into `-` so you will get the correct `data-href` in the generated HTML.

```
@using (Html.BeginForm(null, null, 
    new { ReturnUrl = ViewBag.ReturnUrl }, FormMethod.Post, 
    new { data_href = "/User/Account/Login"}))
```